# Free earthquake multiple line graph in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm looking for a FREE JavaScript multiple lines chart graph , like this :

[image]

One that I can use for commercial use .

I've looked in JqPlot documentation [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/line-charts.html#) , but didn't find something like that .

Can anyone direct me to a FREE JS multiple lines chart graph that I can use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use  Google Chart

here is [js Bin](http://jsbin.com/jolepedege/1/)

```js
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
      data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

      data.addRows([
        [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
        [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
        [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
        [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
        [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
        [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
        [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
        [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
          subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="linechart_material"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Help Link https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Material

Answer (score 2):

jqPlot is more than capable of what you want. The line graph takes an array of arrays, each array representing a separate line:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbVLVq

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,5,3,8,2,5], [50,1,21,4,3,6,8,5]]);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) which is very good and easy to use. You can see a line chart example [here](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/site.html) and [there](http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html).

Alternatively, [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) can do the trick, as well as [C3.js](http://c3js.org/)

All of these free, open-source librairies are based on d3.js (still pure Javascript), which you don't need to know since they have simple APIs.